# Parameterized JUnit tests in conjunction with CdiRunner?

Tags: junit, cdi

Let's take this simple JUnit test which runs with a `CdiRunner`.

```
@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
public class MyTests {

  @Inject
  MyService service;

  @Test
  public void testFoo() {
    service.doSomething();
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
  }

}
```

I'd like to extend this test so that it uses the `Parameterized.class`of JUnit. However additionally annotating the class does not work.

```
@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MyTests {

  @Inject
  MyService service;

  @Test
  public void testFoo() {
    service.doSomething();
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
  }

}
```

How can I implment a data-driven test using the `CdiRunner`?

Comment: What about junit5? See: https://github.com/BrynCooke/cdi-unit/issues/103, Ejb-Cdi-Unit supports JUnit5 if you use the old branch: https://github.com/1and1/ioc-unit/tree/ejb-cdi-unit